# Cannot get SVG as a component to render in CRA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg

I've written the following TypeScript component:

```
import React from 'react'
import cx from 'classnames'

/* import SVGs */
import { ReactComponent as Phone } from '../images/phone.svg' 
import { ReactComponent as AtDesk } from '../images/at-desk.svg' 
import { ReactComponent as Available } from '../images/available.svg' 
import { ReactComponent as Blushing } from '../images/blushing.svg' 
import { ReactComponent as Skills } from '../images/skills.svg' 
import { ReactComponent as Smile } from '../images/smile.svg' 
import { ReactComponent as Beach } from '../images/beach.svg' 

const selectMiniMe = (name: string): any => {
    switch (name) {
      case 'available' :
        return <Available />
      case 'at-desk':
        return <AtDesk/>
      case 'blushing':
        return <Blushing />
      case 'skills':
        return <Skills />
      case 'phone':
        return <Phone />
        case 'beach':
          return <Beach />
      case 'smile':
      default:
        return <Smile />
    }
  }

/* Import Types */
import Props from './types/props'

/* import Styles */
import styles from './styles.module.scss'

/* Render Component */
export const MiniMe: React.FC<Props> = ({ name, width, position, classes}: Props) => {
  return <div className={cx(styles['mini-me'], styles[`w-${width}`], classes)}>
    { selectMiniMe(name) }
    </div>
}


export default MiniMe
```

This component renders without issue as a story in storybook. Everything looks and works exactly as expected and no errors are reported.

When I try to import that component into a brand new Create-React-App TypeScript app. I get the following error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `MiniMe`.
```

I suspect the issue is loader related but as far as I can tell, I'm doing everything the way that CRA is already configured to work with so I have no idea where it's failing.

For additional reference, here is a link to the repo: https://github.com/foxleigh81/alex-foxleigh-portfolio/tree/2020

I've also managed to find a reference to this exact issue - which as far as I can tell was actually fixed in CRA in 2018, so I've no idea why I'm getting this issue here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/5573

Comment: Unable to [replicate in CRA](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/cra-svg). If you're using some sort of library bundler (custom webpack config, rollup, gulp, etc), then most likely your compiled output is invalid. Without a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's a guessing game.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try a brand new CRA app and see if it works in that one. Thanks very much for trying it out :)

Comment: No, that didn't help sadly. The issue happens even with a fresh app.

Comment: declare type definition for svg in any `.d.ts` file and include that in your `tsconfig`

Answer (score 2):

Try to declare the svg module

add this to
`// / <reference types="react-scripts" /> declare module '*.svg';`
in your react-app-env.d.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your repository it seems you are using **learna and react setup** and are **not using `create-react-app` completely**, as I don't see all dependencies that are added to new react app created using `create-react-app` there in your codebase and hence I am not sure using `svg` as component will work.

That being said, that will not prevent you from using `img` tag. I have updated your code and it is working as expected:

```
import React from 'react'
import cx from 'classnames'

/* Import Types */
import Props from './types/props'

/* import SVGs */
import Phone from './images/phone.svg' 
import AtDesk from './images/at-desk.svg' 
import Available from './images/available.svg' 
import Blushing from './images/blushing.svg' 
import Skills from './images/skills.svg' 
import Smile from './images/smile.svg' 
import Beach from './images/beach.svg' 


/* import styles */
import styles from './styles.module.scss'

/* Render component */
export const MiniMe: React.FC<Props> = ({ name, width, position, classes}: Props) => {
  const selectMiniMe = (name: string): any => {
    switch (name) {
      case 'available' :
        return <img src={Available} />
      case 'at-desk':
        return <img src={AtDesk} />
      case 'blushing':
        return <img src={Blushing} />
      case 'skills':
        return <img src={Skills} />
      case 'phone':
        return <img src={Phone} />
        case 'beach':
          return <img src={Beach} />
      case 'smile':
      default:
        return <img src={Smile} />
    }
  }

  return <div className={cx(styles['mini-me'], styles[`w-${width}`], classes)}>
    {selectMiniMe(name)}
    </div>
}

export default MiniMe
```

Comment: The `client` package was made using create-react-app. Unless there is an issue with CRA and Lerna I am unfamiliar with, I'm not sure why this is an issue :(

Comment: @AlezFoxleigh how source files were created matters less than how package is build and in your setup I did not see react-scripts used at all to build the package put of source code that could be one of the reasons.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I replaced `react-scripts` with `craco` as that allows me to modify the webpack config. However, I also tried this with a fresh app which still had `react-scripts` and unfortunately suffered the same issue.

I've done your suggestion of using an img tag for now and hopefully when I come to do the next phase (which needs inline SVG) I will have found the solution. :)